# Вставка текста в svg

Tags: svg, javascript

Подскажите, каким образом можно вставить текст в svg при помощи JS.
Весь код генерируется скриптом, кружки, квадратики и т.п. вставляется без проблем, а вот текст не хочет.

При том, что если сгенерированный код вставить в документ, то все нормально отображается, а динамически что-то никак.

[Вот пример](http://jsfiddle.net/XGX53/)

Comment: лучше `title.appendChild(document.createTextNode("text"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

одна ошибка кроется в использовании `innerHTML` - SVG это XML, не HTML. `textContent` по идее должен подходить, но на примере он что-то не очень спешит это делать

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался, именно в этом проблема, и еще, то что текст добавлялся через createElement, а не createElementNS.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вставить текст нужен textContent

```js
document.querySelectorAll('text').forEach(item => {
  item.textContent = 666
});
```

```html
<svg>
  <text x="0" y="15" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">1</text>
  <text x="0" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">2</text>
  <text x="0" y="55" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">11</text>
  <text x="0" y="75" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">-1</text>
  <text x="0" y="95" font-family="Verdana" font-size="15">-6</text>
</svg>
```